# How can I sort a list that has potential parents with the parent objects first in the list?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

In C#, if I have a list of objects, where each object can have a parent, and each parent can have a parent (x combinations), how is the best way to sort the list so that all the parent objects are first in the list?

Here is the object structure:

```
class test
{
    int id { get; set; }
    int parentId { get; set; }
    bool hasParentObject { get; set; }
}
```

Here is an example of some objects:

Object a:

```
id = 1;
parentId = 0;
hasParentObject = false;
```

Object b:

```
id = 2;
parentId = 1;
hasParentObject = true;
```

Object c:

```
id = 3;
parentId = 2;
hasParentObject = true;
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**

With the following code, how can the code be modified so that if an object does not have a parent, the object is in the list before any objects that do have parents?

Code:

```
class Test : IComparable<Test>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public bool HasParentObject { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Test other)
    {
        if(!this.HasParentObject)
            return 1;
        else if(!other.HasParentObject)
            return 1;
        else if(other.HasParentObject && this.HasParentObject)
            return ParentId.CompareTo(other.ParentId);
        else if(other.HasParentObject)
            return 1;
        else 
            return -1; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement the `IComparable` itherface for your class and then use the `Sort` method of the list.

```
class Test : IComparable<Test>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public bool HasParentObject { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Test other)
    {
        if(other.HasParentObject && this.HasParentObject)
            return ParentId.CompareTo(other.ParentId);
        else if(other.HasParentObject)
            return 1;
        else 
            return -1; 
    }
}
```

Please look [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0rChu0) for a working example based on your post's data.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to modify the code so that the objects that do not have a parent are first in the list?

Comment: Of course it can be done. You should change a bit the conditions we check. For instance one of the cases it would be that the other hasn't any parent. If this....return 1. The same holds for the this....and si on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you would want the objects that are parents first in the list (Optional: Ordered by ID), then you want the objects that aren't parents to follow the parent objects in the list (Optional: Ordered by ID).

This isn't a one liner, but I think it does what you're asking

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Test> tests = new List<Test>
        {
            new Test() { Id = 6, ParentId = 2, HasParentObject = true },
            new Test() { Id = 2, ParentId = 0, HasParentObject = false },
            new Test() { Id = 1, ParentId = 0, HasParentObject = true },
            new Test() { Id = 4, ParentId = 1, HasParentObject = true }
        };

        // Get the parents sorted
        List<Test> sortedTests = tests.Where(t => tests.FindIndex(t2 => t2.ParentId == t.Id) != -1)
            .OrderBy(t => t.Id)
            .ToList();

        // Add those that aren't parents sorted
        sortedTests.AddRange(tests.Where(t => tests.FindIndex(t2 => t2.ParentId == t.Id) == -1)
            .OrderBy(t => t.Id));
        sortedTests.ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} ParentId: {1}", t.Id, t.ParentId));
    }
}

class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public bool HasParentObject { get; set; }
}
```

Results:

```
ID: 1 ParentId: 0
ID: 2 ParentId: 0
ID: 4 ParentId: 1
ID: 6 ParentId: 2
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FaMeYF)

Answer (score 0):

if one can assume the hasParentObject property is public

```
    public List<test> l;

    public List<test> sortList(List<test> _l)
    {
        return _l.OrderByDescending(a => a.hasParentObject).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use new Comparison overload of Sort method -  `.Sort(new Comparison<test>(expression))`

For instance :

```
        List<test> list = new List<test>()
        {
            new test() { id=1, hasParentObject = false, parentId = 0 },
            new test() { id=2, hasParentObject = true, parentId = 1 },
            new test() { id=3, hasParentObject = false, parentId = 0 },
            new test() { id=4, hasParentObject = true, parentId = 3 },
        };

        list.Sort((s1, s2) => s1.parentId > s2.parentId ? 1 : (s1.parentId < s2.parentId ? -1 : 0));            

        foreach (var item in list)
            Console.WriteLine(item.id);            

        Console.ReadKey();
```